# Can not start redis client

Tags: redis

I can start the redis server but it seems that I can not start redis client!

```
# date
Thu Mar  8 09:21:16 IST 2012

# tail redis.log
[20936] 08 Mar 09:21:17 - DB 2: 1512101 keys (0 volatile) in 2097152 slots HT.
[20936] 08 Mar 09:21:17 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 105972712 bytes in use

# lsof -i :6379
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
redis-ser 20936 root    4u  IPv4  89088       TCP *:6379 (LISTEN)

# ps aux | grep redis
root     20936  0.1  2.6 133456 105400 pts/4   Sl   09:06   0:01 src/redis-server redis.conf
root     21003  0.0  0.0  61192   768 pts/4    S+   09:21   0:00 grep redis
```

When I try to start the client, it does nothing. No error, no standard out. The echo $? shows that the command was successful.

```
# /src/redis-cli
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redis client file got truncated because of the wrongly put ">" sign instead of "|" in shell script. client will not start after that.